# Trouble when using expression IN

Tags: expression, hsqldb, jdbctemplate

Use: db: HSQLDB, jdbctemplate.

I created tables:

```
    <SELECTED_DATE ID="1" DATE_VALUE="2018-02-02 00:00:00.000000"/>
    <SELECTED_DATE ID="2" DATE_VALUE="2018-02-03 00:00:00.000000"/>
    <SELECTED_DATE ID="3" DATE_VALUE="2018-02-04 00:00:00.000000"/>
    <SELECTED_DATE ID="4" DATE_VALUE="2018-02-05 00:00:00.000000"/>
    <SELECTED_DATE ID="5" DATE_VALUE="2018-02-07 00:00:00.000000"/>
    <SELECTED_DATE ID="6" DATE_VALUE="2018-02-08 00:00:00.000000"/>
```

How to use `select * from SELECTED_DATE where DATE_VALUE in ( '2018-02-08', ... );`

this causes an error: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: data type of expression is not boolean`

or `select * from SELECTED_DATE where DATE_VALUE IN ELEMENTS('2018-02-08', ...);`

this causes an error: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ELEMENTS required: (`

but such `select * from SELECTED_DATE where DATE_VALUE = ( '2018-02-08');` its work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date column is in fact a TIMESTAMP column.

For IN predicates, you need to declare the type of the values:

```
select * from SELECTED_DATE where DATE_VALUE in ( DATE'2018-02-02', DATE'2018-02-03');
```

The above works. If your SELECT statement does not still work, please report the complete statement.